# Pass polymorphic record to foreign function

Tags: purescript

I have `R1` and `R2` record types and I need to pass either `R1` or `R2` to a foreign function (it can handle either r1 or r2 record structure) is it possible to do this (I thought maybe via conversion to Foreign Object)?

Or do I need to declare two different foreign imports (with different type signatures for passing `R1` and `R2`) pointing to the same js function?

Another way I found using `unsafeCoerce` for type conversion:

```
foreign import data R1orR2 ∷ Type

fromR1 :: R1 -> R1orR2
fromR1 = unsafeCoerce

fromR2 :: R2 -> R1orR2
fromR2 = unsafeCoerce
```

So maybe there some other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing FFI bindings, `unsafeCoerce` is quite ok: after all, `foreign import` has all the same drawbacks already, so you're not really losing anything.

And yes, what you came up with - `R1orR2` - is the right approach that's used quite frequently in FFI bindings.

You may also want to check out [`undefined-is-not-a-problem`](https://github.com/paluh/purescript-undefined-is-not-a-problem) and [`untagged-union`](https://github.com/jvliwanag/purescript-untagged-union) libraries. They offer some more advanced and generalized techniques in this area.